# On the usage of Proj4Js->tmerc.js

Tags: openlayers-2, coordinate-system, proj

I am using "proj4js and OpenLayers" for my mapping. I got the projection and datum (which is based on "Transverse Mercator") of a local plane and 
this plane is part of a grid which returns coordinates of local points in the form of Northings and Eastings.

Now, as we know that OpenLayers accepts latitude and longitude hence I am doing transformation of Northings, Eastings of a point to lat, long using Transverse Mercator (tmerc.js)

Script of proj4js...

So my question is will this be enough for the correct transformation or is there is any thought or suggestion you would like to give regarding the transformation script I am using?

Comment: do you know the epsg code of the projection your data is in? if so proj4js probably has the exact transform.

Comment: yes epsg code is 62036405

Comment: but epsg code is nothing to do with transformation. epsg code just provides projection as well as datus details as an input to proj4js...proj4js then uses this input along with "tmerc.js" to actually transform your data